# How can I show a progress bar of the file upload in my html

Tags: node.js, file-upload, progress-bar

I have a file upload in node js.  I want to show a line displaying *upload started / upload failed / upload completed* and a graphic progress bar.

How can I implement this?

**Node.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');

var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
       destination: function (req, file, cb) {
         cb(null, './upload');
       },
       filename: function (req, file, cb) {
         cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now());
       }
    });

var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).array('file', 3);

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send( {success: 'File uploaded!'});
})

router.post('/upload', function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        console.log('Selected Files: ', req.files);
        if(err){
            res.end("Error: '" , err , "'");
        }else{
        console.log('Files uploaded!');
        res.sendStatus(204);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**HTML**

```
<form enctype   =  "multipart/form-data"
      action    =  "/upload"
      method    =  "POST"
>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<p></p>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
<p id="success">{{success}}</p>
```

Comment: What is working and what is not working? Since you put code we assume you have tried to implement this yourself. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I wanted a status comment in the paragraph success which shows something like upload started / upload failed / upload completed. And with the progress bar I didn't know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Use XMLHttpRequest and .addEventListener("progress") on the client side to submit the form